# Python NetCDF: Read "filling off" as "filling on"

Tags: python, netcdf4

I seem to have a netcdf file that has been created with "filling off". How do I read it with "filling on"?

That is, what I would really like is the library to automatically figure out when a variable is missing, as it seems to do with "filling on". Is there a way to do this?

Output from ipython:

```
In [1]: import netCDF4 as netcdf

In [2]: nc = netcdf.Dataset("/tmp/somefile.nc")

In [3]: nc.variables["time"]

Out[3]:
<type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
int32 time(event, altitude)
long_name: Msec Since Midnight
units: msec
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (43627, 372)
filling off

In [4]: nc.variables["time"][:]

Out[4]: 
array([[   86441314,    86441359,    86441404, ...,    86457871,
       86457915, -2147483647],
   [   86502423,    86502378,    86502332, ...,    86485825,
       86485737, -2147483647],
   [   86557293,    86557337,    86557383, ...,    86573857,
       86573906, -2147483647],
   ..., 
   [   86355650,    86355607,    86355560, ...,    86338941,
       86338895,    86338848]], dtype=int32)

In [5]: netcdf.default_fillvals["i4"]

Out[5]: -2147483647
```

The `-2147483647` in `Out[4]` should be a missing value (`--`).

ncdump seem to figure it out, as I would like it to (`_`):

```
ncdump /tmp/somefile.nc
```

Output from ncdump:

```
....
time =
....
86457636, 86457685, 86457733, 86457779, 86457824, 86457871, 86457915, _,
....
```

Comment: Are all values you have in the file positive? If that is the case just test if the value is negative and replace it with `None`. Otherwise you can test for the negative integer limit (which is the value you're getting for your missing number). 
from the python documentation:
`sys.maxint`
" The largest positive integer supported by Python’s regular integer type. This is at least 2**31-1. The largest negative integer is -maxint-1 — the asymmetry results from the use of 2’s complement binary arithmetic."

Comment: In this specific case they are all positive, but that is not always the case in the other data. In fact, something alike your suggestion is my current workaround. But... in other cases (seem to be with "filling on") the library figures it out, all by itself. I was just wondering if there is a way to make it do this in all cases.